# Thickness animation trouble? (with Begin function parameters)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

There is Main frame on which there is a button and control and also stackpanel. Attempting to move worked animation from xaml to .cs I have wrote next cool function)):

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
int heightBottom = 100;

System.Windows.Thickness th = stackPanel1.Margin;
            th.Top = stackPanel1.Margin.Top + heightBottom;
ThicknessAnimation animStackPanel1 = new ThicknessAnimation
            {
                From = stackPanel1.Margin,
                To = th,
                AccelerationRatio = 0.2,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                DecelerationRatio = 0.8,
                Duration = DURATION
            };
System.Windows.Thickness th2 = fxPSEditorView.Margin;
            th2.Right = fxPSEditorView.Margin.Right - heightBottom;
            th2.Bottom = fxPSEditorView.Margin.Bottom - heightBottom;

            ThicknessAnimation animPSEditorView = new ThicknessAnimation
            {
                From = fxPSEditorView.Margin,
                To = th2,
                AccelerationRatio = 0.2,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
                DecelerationRatio = 0.8,
                Duration = DURATION
            };
Storyboard.SetTarget(animPSEditorView, fxPSEditorView);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fxPSEditorView, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));
            sb.Children.Add(animPSEditorView);
Storyboard.SetTarget(animStackPanel1, stackPanel1);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(stackPanel1, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));
            sb.Children.Add(animStackPanel1);
sb.Begin();//null reference error here! 
};
```

As I understand I must specify TWO parameters for sb.Begin - one for stackPanel1 and the other is for fxPSEditorView. But It does not takes a set of objects as first parameter.
 Any  ideas how to run this animation will be wellcome ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two parameters, but you should pass the control which contains the controls which are being animated (which need to be in the same name-scope). Read the documentation of [`Begin(FrameworkElement)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605709.aspx).

Comment: I have found error myself :THIS IS  NOT RIGHT Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fxPSEditorView, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty)); THIS IS RIGHT Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animPSEditorView, new PropertyPath(MarginProperty));